# How to solve Linear Diophantine equations in programming?

Tags: c++, algorithm, equation, algebra

I have read about Linear Diophantine equations such as `ax+by=c` are called diophantine equations and give an integer solution only if `gcd(a,b) divides c`.

These equations are of great importance in programming contests. I was just searching the Internet, when I came across this problem. I think its a variation of diophantine equations.

Problem :

I have two persons,Person X and Person Y both are standing in the middle of a rope. Person X can jump either A or B units to the left or right in one move. Person Y can jump either C or D units to the left or right in one move. Now, I'm given a number K and I have to find the no. of possible positions on the rope in the range [-K,K] such that both the persons can reach that position using their respective movies any number of times. (A,B,C,D and K are given in question).

My solution:

I think the problem can be solved mathematically using diophantine equations.

I can form an equation for Person X like `A x_1 + B y_1 = C_1 where C_1 belongs to [-K,K]` and similarly for Person Y like `C x_2 + D y_2 = C_2 where C_2 belongs to [-K,K]`.

Now my search space reduces to just finding the number of possible values for which C_1 and C_2 are same. This will be my answer for this problem.

To find those values I'm just finding `gcd(A,B)` and `gcd(C,D)` and then taking the **lcm** of these two **gcd**'s to get `LCM(gcd(A,B),gcd(C,D))` and then simply calculating the number of points in the range [1,K] which are multiples of this **lcm**.

My final answer will be `2*no_of_multiples in [1,K] + 1`.

I tried using the same technique in my C++ code, but it's not working(Wrong Answer).

This is my code :
http://pastebin.com/XURQzymA

My question is: can anyone please tell me if I'm using diophantine equations correctly ?

If yes, can anyone tell me possible cases where my logic fails.

These are some of the test cases which were given on the site with problem statement.

A B C D K are given as input in same sequence and the corresponding output is given on next line :

> 2 4 3 6 7
>
> 3
>
> 1 2 4 5 1
>
> 3
>
> 10 12 3 9 16
>
> 5

This is the link to original problem. I have written the original question in simple language. You might find it difficult, but if you want you can check it:

http://www.codechef.com/APRIL12/problems/DUMPLING/

Please give me some test cases so that I can figure out where am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely it is against the rules of the contest to ask for help? Can you wait for the contest to end first?

Comment: Can I expect some test case or at least some hint ?

Comment: Dude, your code compiles and runs and gives the correct answers for the examples.  What's the problem exactly?

PS: your gcd algorithm doesn't need the arguments in order; you can elide 18 lines of code.

Comment: @EddieEdwards: Yeah.I know my code works fine on examples but don't know why am I getting wrong answer on codechef.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example where it fails?

Comment: Got it - see answer below - it's all in the precise wording of the question.

Comment: You shouldn't misuse the community by asking problems which are from an ongoing contest(which is against the rules of that contest).

Comment: It is not against the rules of that contest.  Check the rules page here http://www.codechef.com/APRIL12/.

Comment: @EddieEdwards, _Please do not discuss strategy, suggestions or tips in the comments during a live contest. Posting questions clarifying the problem statement is ok._ Yeah, sure, asking for help on any other website seems ok :|

Comment: Yeah, well :)  He's solved the problem on his own anyway.  Just a small detail missed.  And he seems to have disappeared without trace now he's got the fix so boy do I feel good for helping him :)

Answer (score 14):

## Solving Linear Diophantine equations

`ax + by = c` and `gcd(a, b)` divides `c`.

1. Divide a, b and c by gcd(a,b).
2. Now gcd(a,b) == 1
3. Find solution to aU + bV = 1 using [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)
4. Multiply equation by c. Now you have a(Uc) + b (Vc) = c
5. You found solution `x = U*c` and `y = V * c`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the input values are 64-bit (up to 10^18) so the LCM can be up to 128 bits large, therefore `l` can overflow.  Since `k` is 64-bit, an overflowing `l` indicates `k` = 0 (so answer is 1).  You need to check this case.

For instance:

```
unsigned long long l=g1/g; // cannot overflow
unsigned long long res;
if ((l * g2) / g2 != l)
{
    // overflow case - l*g2 is very large, so k/(l*g2) is 0
    res = 0;
}
else
{
    l *= g2;
    res = k / l;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply but as told by you I was working on the problem.The thing pointed out by you seems to be correct,so I tried solving the problem in Java using BigInteger but got NZEC :( I'm still working on it and looking forward to solve it.

Comment: The fix above does it with your original code in a few lines.  You just need to check for overflow (multiply then divide, and if the result is correct you did *not* overflow) and set `res = 0` if it happens.